# Get the selected value of a ListBox in a SelectionCell

Tags: gwt, select, listbox

I have read the [relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565790/how-to-dynamically-update-the-choices-in-a-selectioncell-using-gwt) but I am still not be able to find the answer to my problem. I am using a [SelectionCell](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/cell/client/SelectionCell.html) in a column in a Datagrid which obviously contains  a ListBox. However it does not provide direct access to ListBox and therefore I cannot find the way to **get the selected value** when the user selects an option of the ListBox. I am aware of the method onBrowserEvent but it does return anything. I need the value selected by the user to save it in a database. I need probably something like the line of codes contained in the above method:

```
SelectElement select = parent.getFirstChild().cast();
String newValue = options.get(select.getSelectedIndex());
```

The parent is however not available to any custom Method, so what I could do in order to have the selected value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're looking for `FieldUpdater`. Sample usage in the question you linked to.

Comment: I don' t think this is the case. FieldUpdater serves the addition of new values to the Widget. I cannot detect a way (or a method) to return the selected value even with the Upadater. If my impression is false I would appreciate a somewhat more detailed explanation.

Comment: `FieldUpdated` should be called whenever the value in the cell changes, with the new value and the object corresponding to the row passed as arguments (the idea being that you'll call the appropriate setter on the row object, hence the name): the `Column` gets the value out of the object, the `FieldUpdater` signals the new value so it can be put in the object (or pushed in a queue of things to save [for instance](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellSampler))

Comment: Ok, the case is solved with the FieldUpdater. One must use a set method on the object variable in the update method as object.setSomething() in order for the desired value to be changed. A little bit devious though, not apparent and noticeable immediately.