# gwt add listBox to cellTable

Tags: gwt, listbox

I build application in gwt and I have cellTabe with 3 columns.
I saw this example from gwt showcase
http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTable
but I need listBox in every row with other items or hide listBox if no items to show
example for my CellTable I need:

```
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| column 1: | name  column 2: lastName | column 3: favorites                     |
|-----------|--------------------------|-----------------------------------------|
| gal       | lavie                    | listBox with basketball,football,tennis |
| eyal      | lavie                    | listBox with horses,swimming            |
| ela       | lavie                    | no items so hide listBox                |
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and I need to add changedSelectedListener to each listBox because if listBox changed I need to show more data on screen
how I can do this?
thank you

Comment: could you please modify your question bit to make it understanble. what is Gal lavie listbox? What is row with other item? Please show as design if possible.

Comment: ok this what I need http://i250.photobucket.com/albums/gg253/gallavie/Untitled_zps7af963e4.png

Comment: Please check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565790/how-to-dynamically-update-the-choices-in-a-selectioncell-using-gwt , I hope this is what you are looking for.